# Construct an multidiamensitonal array from variables and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Honorable Xperts, Please help me to construct an multidimensional array. I've some variable like:

```
$subject_name = Algorithom
$subject_code = 30103
$department_name = Computer Science
$department_short_name = CSE
$teacher_name = Md. Kibria
$date = 09-APR-2015
$time = 12:00am
$student = // it's an array
$status = // it's an array
```

and two array like these:

```
print_r($student) =
Array ( [0] => Md. Tushar Ahmed [1] => Mrs. Monira Akter [2] => JOYNAB 
AKTER [3] => BEAUTY AKTER [4] => PURABI BARUA [5] => SETU BISWAS )

print_r($status) =
Array ( [0] => present [1] => absent [2] => absent [3] => leave [4] =>
present [5] => present )
```

Nw I want an multidimensional array like this:

```
array (
array([0]=>algorithom [1]=> 30103 [2]=>30103 [3]=>computer science   
[4]=>cse [5]=>md. kibria [6]=>09-APR-2015 [7]=>12:00AM [8]=>Md. Tushar 
Ahmed [9]=> present),

array([0]=>algorithom [1]=> 30103 [2]=>30103 [3]=>computer science 
[4]=>cse [5]=>md. kibria [6]=>09-APR-2015 [7]=>12:00AM [8]=> Mrs. Monira 
Akter [9]=> absent),

array([0]=>algorithom [1]=> 30103 [2]=>30103 [3]=>computer science 
[4]=>cse [5]=>md. kibria [6]=>09-APR-2015 [7]=>12:00AM [8]=> JOYNAB 
AKTER [9]=> leave),

 and so on . . . .

 )
```

This Multidimensional array must have to be come out from a loop.

pls help me to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a simple array assignment, you should consult the manual for this instead http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over $students adding those variables and corresponding $status value:

```
$array = array();
foreach($students as $k=>$v){
    $array[] = array(
        $subject_name, 
        $subject_code, 
        $subject_code, 
        $department_name, 
        $department_short_name, 
        $teacher_name, 
        $date, 
        $time, 
        $v, 
        $status[$k]
     );
}
```

You repeated $subject_code, so I did it too, but I am not sure it was on purpose.

Comment: Wow! it nicely works for me. thanks a lot. ya i didn't want to iterate $subject_code at all. moreover thanks.